# How to remove wallarm installation?

Tags: email, centos7, yum

I want to remove the wallarm installation on my Centos7. I did this with yum remove wallarm, but in the mail-log file I still see wallarm passing by every 10 seconds:

```
webserver postfix/local[6833]: 337CC181C855: to=
<wallarm@webserver.example.com>, orig_to=<
wallarm>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent 
(delivered to mailbox)
Feb 21 00:03:03 webserver postfix/qmgr[24359]: 337CC181C855: removed
```

How can I completely remove all packages related to Wallarm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did yum autoremove wallarm. That way it also removes all dependencies.